# network site domain mapping still applied after being removed

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I have a sub-domain network installation on `www.example.com`

One of the sites is `rabbit.example.com`

This site used to have a domain mapping to `www.rabbit.com`.

I removed this mapping.

However, when I go to `http://rabbit.example.com/wp-admin`, it forwards me to `http://www.rabbit.com/wp-admin`

I have checked the site settings for `rabbit.example.com`, and the base URL and home URL are set to `rabbit.example.com`.

I have double-checked the domain mapping is no longer there.

I do not have a caching plugin installed.

The site's database table, `wp_10_options`, has the site URL as `rabbit.example.com`

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you using to apply the domain mapping? A plugin?

Comment: How long ago was the mapping removed? 301 redirects get cached by browsers (and sometimes networks)

Comment: I am using WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin.  The mapping was removed about 3 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to see if the .htaccess file has still some references to `www.rabbit.com`, maybe the plugin you used to make the redirect has modified that file.

Hope this helps,
Marco

Comment: No, the domain mapper plugin does not insert domains into .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to site_url in database, there is also a Home Field.
Look for that in the options table as well and make sure it reflects your new, or unmapped, domain.

You can also try to update the URLs in wp-config directly:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

But before trying the second, make sure to try the first.

Comment: The Home field is set correctly.  I don't believe you can update a network site's URL in wp-config.

Comment: Of course you have `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'rabbit.example.com');` in wp-config.php tho...